# Context free grammar design - Why is this not allowed?

Tags: programming-languages, grammar, context-free-grammar

I am still learning about the context free grammar. A particular kind of question I have doubt about is coming up with a grammar for some specific patterns.

For example:

"At least 3 zeros."

Why not just come up with a grammar that is like: S -> 000 ?
What rule forbids this kind of grammar?

Comment: No rule forbids that kind of grammar, it's a perfectly legal grammar (which matches exactly three zeros, not at least three zeros). Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @sepp2k After writing things down, I know what is wrong with my answer. However, could you please suggest some ways to solve this kind of questions in which you have to come up with a CFG?

Answer (score 0):

What it could limit your grammar (forbid some constructs) is the grammar form that you use. In the [Chomsky normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form) (CNF) the rules are one of:

```
A → BC
A → a
S → ε
```

In the [Greibach normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form) (GNF) the rules are:

```
A → aBCD...
```

There is and the [Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), where you have more richer syntax. Then the [Extended Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) (EBNF) and at best the [Augmented Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) (ABNF).

At least 3 zeroes in CNF:

```
S → AB
A → ZZ
B → ZB
B → 0
Z → 0
```

At least 3 zeroes in GNF:

```
S → 0A
A → 0B
B → 0B
B → 0
```

At least 3 zeroes in BNF:

```
<S> ::= "000" <A>
<A> ::= "0" <A> | ""
```

At least 3 zeroes in EBNF:

```
S = "000", { "0" }
```

At least 3 zeroes in ABNF:

```
S = 3*"0"
```

Some recognition (parsing) algorithms require the grammar to be in some form. For this reason you have to convert the grammar, if it is not already in it.